# Using Row Level Security with a tenant_id that is NOT the SQL connection's username

Tags: postgresql

Is this doable with a straight up SQL connection? If so how?

I want to activate PostgreSQL's [Row Level Security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) to enforce multi-tenancy on a table like that has a `tenant_id` like this one:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  tenant_id UUID NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

but I **do not** want the DB Username the tenant id's UUID?

```sql
CREATE POLICY tenant_isolation_policy ON my_table
USING (tenant_id::TEXT = _______);
```

I've seen [examples](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/multi-tenant-data-isolation-with-postgresql-row-level-security/) with `USING (tenant_id::TEXT = current_user);`, but that means that the DB USER is the tenant id's UUID. I'd like to have my username as `my_friendly_client_name` or whatever.

I don't have an API or any code in front of my DB, it's a straight up SQL Connection.

I tried using ROLE and `current_role`, but I'm stuck. Something like:

```sql
CREATE USER "my_friendly_client_name" WITH PASSWORD '______';
CREATE ROLE "12345678-1234-1234-1234-abcdef012345"; -- the actual tenant_id
GRANT "12345678-1234-1234-1234-abcdef012345" TO "my_friendly_client_name";
```

but I'm stuck. Can it be done? And is there a performance hit?

Comment: You can use a subquery in the `USING` clause, so you can look up the tenant's UUID in a PostgreSQL table.

Answer (score 0):

With Laurenz Albe's comment, I managed to get to this solution:

```sql
CREATE POLICY tenant_isolation_policy ON my_table
USING (tenant_id = (
    -- look up the associated user role, it's the 'tenant_id'
    select rolname::UUID 
    from pg_user
    join pg_auth_members on pg_user.usesysid = pg_auth_members.member
    join pg_roles on pg_roles.oid = pg_auth_members.roleid
    WHERE pg_user.usename = current_user)
);
```